# (node:23424) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: body is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

I have read too many answers here and in github but I do not get to solve my problem. Here it is,
Using postman:
POST --> http://localhost:3000/api/employees;
headers: Content-type application/json

simple json:
{
"city" : "New York",
"name" : "Joseph"
}

and I have body-parser installed in node_modules

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000)  

app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/*+json' }));

app.use(bodyParser.raw({ type: 'application/vnd.custom-type' }));

app.use(bodyParser.text({ type: 'text/html' }));
```

Comment: http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html#examples

Comment: Please give a [mre]. *Where* is body undefined?

Comment: sometimes there can be conflict if you use 2 different types of body parsers use only one

Comment: Both express.json() and bodyparser.json() do the same thing. bodyParser was added back to Express in release 4.16.0.  I dont see body named variable declared anywhere in your code

Answer (score 0):

```
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

const { Mongoose } = require ('./database');

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);   

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(express.json());

app.use('/api/employees', require('./routes/employee.routes'));

app.listen (app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log(`server on port ${app.get('port')}`);
}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys.
And this is the response in the server after the request:

POST /api/employees - - ms - -
(node:23604) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: body is not defined.

And this was the second try:

```
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const cors = require('cors');

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

const { Mongoose } = require ('./database');

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);   // Así luego se puede invocar "port", con el puerto que sea.

app.use(morgan('dev'));

app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/*+json' }));
app.use(bodyParser.raw({ type: 'application/vnd.custom-type' }));
app.use(bodyParser.text({ type: 'text/html' }));

app.use('/api/employees', require('./routes/employee.routes'));


app.listen (app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log(`server on port ${app.get('port')}, majete`);
}
)
```

And the answer:

POST /api/employees - - ms - -
(node:18328) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: body is not defined

This is the controller:

```
employeeCtrl.createEmployee = async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req, body);
    console.log("Estoy en crear employee");
    const employee = new Employee({
        name: req.body.name,
        position: req.body.position,
        office: req.body.office,
        salary: req.body.salary
    });
    await employee.save();
    res.json({ 'status': 'Employee saved' });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I did not explain well.
The problem is in the controller, when I make a simple "console.log(req, body)"

Comment: Any idea, please??? It has to be something trivial... I guess and I can't find out...

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it...
I had 2 modules, index.js and controller.js.
It was necessary to declare the variable in the controller.js

```
const bodyParser = require ('body-parser');
```

I have this variable in both modules, index.js and controller.js. And now it works!!